# get username data from another class in Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parse-platform

So, I created a new PFUser object in one class(RegisterViewController) in which I store the values for the username and password for the signup process of my app. Now, I have another class(LoginViewController) and I want to log in to my app but can't get the correct way to do it because I can't retrieve the data from parse. By the way, I verified that the username and password that I entered in my Registerviewcontroller was saved on parse. But actually, I'm having trouble in retrieving it in another class(LoginViewController)

Please help me! Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Use core data or SQLite to store data. it will work perfect

Comment: Use NSUserDefault for store values

Comment: Store it in the keychain or put it in your application's data manager and pass a reference to that around. NSUserDefaults is not a good place to store sensitive information - it can be read by anyone with access to the device.

Comment: hmmm..so, how do I do it? By the way, I'm using parse it is an online server where I am storing my data. But I'll take a look on what you are suggesting here? Can you post some example codes just to make it clearer for me? Thanks

Comment: [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

Answer (score -1):

When U store your authentication records store them in user defaults like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:password forKey:@"Password"];
```

Then U can reach them from anywhere like this:

```
pass = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
```

Comment: hmmm..does it directly save my data to parse? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It saves it to the disc, so U can get it from anywhere. I don't really

Comment: know what parse is?? Is that your custom class of some kind?

Comment: DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN NSUserDefaults! That's what the keychain is for.

Comment: Oh! nope! By the way, here's a link about parse - https://parse.com/ anyway, thanks for your answers.

Comment: I agree with @Abizern. Also if you want to store the value in the  NSUserDefault you need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: synchronize is called automatically and periodically